# Apply CSS Filter to all but specific sub-elements

Tags: html, css

I need a CSS filter to apply to all elements in a container, except for specific ones. Quick example to explain the situation:

```
<div class="container">
 <img class="one" src="blah" />
 <img class="two" src="blah" />
 <img class="three" src="blah" />
</div>
```

Then I am applying filters as so:

```
.container {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

So the container has the greyscale filter applied to it, and all img in it are turned to grey. However, I want one of the img to not turn to grey:

```
.two {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
 filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

However, this is not working. The filter of the container seems to be overriding the filter of the contained element.
Any ideas how I can get around this? Is there an easy way, or do I have to write up some jQuery to look at all the elements that aren't ".two" and apply the filter to them, rather than the container?

Update: I neglected to mention an important caveat: The container has to be greyscale, due to it having a background-image property that is to also be turned grey. This little snippet is part of more containers that are all going greyscale as well, I'm really just trying to figure out if there's a way to have an overriding exemption to the rule on the parent, since the parent has to have the rule as well.

Comment: Quite simply...NO. `filter`, like `opacity` applies to the parent and **all* *children and cannot be over-ridden by setting a competing style on a child element.

Comment: That's kind of what I was afraid of. Oh well! Guess this has to be done a more complicated way.

Comment: I've been scouring for answers on this as well, and it looks like what @Paulie_D says is true. The answers I see posted on here do not seem to work because if applying `filter` on a container, it __cascades__ its effect down to its children. Any changes you attempt to make on the children elements are additional on top of the `filter`. It seems the only solution is to separate out the element(s) you don't want having a `filter` out of the container element and managing positioning of the elements separate of the container. Or finding an alternative to using `filter` itself

Comment: you could apply a reverse filter on the children ... this is simple if the filter applied to the parent is simple, but if multiple filters are applied to the parent things get tricky quickly - if your use case is simple this might work for you ... what we really need is someone clever with spare time to write an npm package that does all the clever calculations needed to reverse multiple filters!

Answer (score 5):

According to [CSS specifity](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.smashingmagazine.com%2F2007%2F07%2F27%2Fcss-specificity-things-you-should-know%2F&ei=8DqZVaquKqr6ywOTxYjADg&usg=AFQjCNF-kmJZdKfI3dd6SXyNr7HzdGxazA&sig2=U1R-iF7g8psNfX5iSysdQw&bvm=bv.96952980,d.bGQ) rules -

Either put the `.two` after the `.container` in the css,

Or make the `.two` more specific, i.e. `img.two`

**UPDATE**

The `.container` rule is on the `div` itself - not on the images. So the container goes grayscale regardless of what you tell the images to do. Try changing that into `.container img`, and then try incorporating the answers you received.

Comment: Regardless of where I place the css for .two in the file, the filter is being applied to all of the container's elements.

Comment: sadly this answer wouldn't work - As I mentioned in another comment, the container has to have the filter on it as well, since it has a background-image property. Sorry for not making that clear in my original post!

Comment: Hm. Looks like it could be a solution, albeit a complicated one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use > to specify an image that is a child of .container the use not: to specify that you don't want the second image grey

```css
.container > img:not(.two) {
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <img class="one" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
 <img class="two" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
 <img class="three" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fbm9zao/)

```
.container > img:not(.two) {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) to exclude `.two`

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a simple selector X as an argument. It matches an element that is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another negation selector.

```
.container img:not(.two) {
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The container has to have the filter as well, so the filter applies to its background-image. There are also more containers here on higher levels that will also have the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Seven years after this question was asked, I thought I'd come up with a brilliant CSS-native solution to this, using:

- `calc()`
- *CSS Custom Properties*

Hours of experimenting with CSS `filter` have satisfied me that the solution will never work.

Why not? Because functions like `filter: hue-rotate()` are both [more complicated than you might expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70977522/why-is-hue-rotate180deg-not-its-own-inverse) and also, unhelpfully, [unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187905/why-doesnt-hue-rotation-by-180deg-and-180deg-yield-the-original-color).

---

### My first ("clever") solution

*(Calculate reverse transformations - cute, but doesn't work)*

The starting point of my *"clever" solution* was:

> It's well-established that once you apply `filter` to a parent element, that `filter` (much like `opacity`) continues to apply to all descendant elements and there is no way to *mask* a descendant element from that `filter`.

But `filter` simply describes *transformations*, right? And - surely - anything transformed can be *un-transformed* via a transformation which represents a *mirror-image* of the original?

Furthermore, if the original transformation is built in the right way from *CSS Custom Properties*, then it ought to be possible to build the mirror-image transformation using *the same CSS Custom Properties* and `calc()`.

So I came up with something like this:

```js
/*
OTHER CSS CUSTOM PROPERTIES (NOT NECESSARY FOR THIS EXAMPLE)

.square[data-theme="green"] {
  --saturation: 1;
  --contrast: 0.775;
  --brightness: 1.2;
}

.square[data-theme="blue"] {
  --saturation: 1;
  --contrast: 0.775;
  --brightness: 1.2;
}


.filter {
  --lightness: contrast(var(--contrast)) brightness(var(--brightness));
  --hsl-filter: hue-rotate(var(--hue)) saturate(var(--saturation)) var(--lightness);
}

.no-filter {
  --reverse-lightness: contrast(calc(1 / var(--contrast))) brightness(calc(1 / var(--brightness)));
  --reverse-hsl-filter: hue-rotate(calc(0deg - var(--hue))) saturate(calc(1 / var(--saturation))) var(--reverse-lightness);
}
*/
```

```css
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 6;
  margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 92px;
  height: 92px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: rgb(191, 0, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.square:nth-of-type(4) {
  clear: left;
}

.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inner-square {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 127, 0);
}

.square[data-theme="green"] {
  --hue: 112.5deg;
}

.square[data-theme="blue"] {
  --hue: 212.5deg;
}

.filter {
  --hsl-filter: hue-rotate(var(--hue));
  filter: var(--hsl-filter);
}

.no-filter {
  --reverse-hsl-filter: hue-rotate(calc(0deg - var(--hue)));
  filter: var(--reverse-hsl-filter);
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <h2>Original</h2>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="inner-square"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="square filter" data-theme="green">
  <h2>Filtered</h2>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="inner-square"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="square filter" data-theme="green">
  <h2>No-Filter Test</h2>
  <div class="circle no-filter">
    <div class="inner-square"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="square">
  <h2>Original</h2>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="inner-square"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="square filter" data-theme="blue">
  <h2>Filtered</h2>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="inner-square"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="square filter" data-theme="blue">
  <h2>No-Filter Test</h2>
  <div class="circle no-filter">
    <div class="inner-square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's less obvious in the top row (at first glance), but in the second row, the last square (ie. bottom right) clearly shows how this *reverse-transformation* approach is neither robust nor reliable:

- The orange square in the bottom-right square isn't perfect, but it's close enough to the original
- The orange square in the top-right square is less perfect, but it's still passable (just about)
- The red circle in the top-right square isn't perfect, but it's close enough to the original
- The red circle in the bottom-right square **is no good at all**

---

### My second (less clever) solution

*(Make the non-filtered element a sibling instead of a descendant element - less clever but it **does** work)*

We may conclude from the above that the *matrix transformation* initiated by `filter: hue-rotate()` cannot be easily reversed - and that even if a computational way to reverse it consistently via JavaScript can be found - I'm currently doubtful over whether *even that* is possible - it's almost certainly not going to be possible via CSS `calc()`.

Alternatively, we can turn the *descendant elements* we don't want to be affected by the `filter` into ***siblings*** of the element which has the CSS `filter` applied to it, instead:

```css
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 6;
  margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 92px;
  height: 92px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container:nth-of-type(4) {
  clear: left;
}

.square {
  width: 92px;
  height: 92px;
  background-color: rgb(191, 0, 0);
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inner-square {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 127, 0);
}

.container[data-theme="green"] {
  --hue: 112.5deg;
}

.container[data-theme="blue"] {
  --hue: 212.5deg;
}

.filter {
  --hsl-filter: hue-rotate(var(--hue));
  filter: var(--hsl-filter);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Original</h2>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="inner-square"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" data-theme="green">
  <h2>Filtered</h2>
  <div class="square filter"></div>
  <div class="circle filter">
    <div class="inner-square"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" data-theme="green">
  <h2>No-Filter Test</h2>
  <div class="square filter"></div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="inner-square"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Original</h2>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="inner-square"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" data-theme="blue">
  <h2>Filtered</h2>
  <div class="square filter"></div>
  <div class="circle filter">
    <div class="inner-square"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" data-theme="blue">
  <h2>No-Filter Test</h2>
  <div class="square filter"></div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="inner-square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This second solution works perfectly, but it requires the **HTML** to be restructured and the **CSS** adjusted to compensate:

- the `filtered` element from the original setup needs to be placed within a *container element*
- the non-filtered descendant of the filtered element now needs to become a *sibling* of the `filtered` element, within the same container
- finally, the non-filtered sibling needs to be re-positioned within the container so that it displays in the same place as before, back when it was a descendant

After taking some time to re-arrange markup and re-adjust styles, we can achieve the originally intended effect with some elements *filtered* and other elements *non-filtered*.

This second approach feels much less elegant than calculating *mirror-image colour-transformations* via *CSS Custom Properties* and `calc()` but until some kind of *filter mask* like:

- `filter-apply: all | none` // *or even (2 - n), (n + 3) etc.*

is introduced into **CSS**...

##### ... the *only* way for a *child-element* to be masked from a `filter` is to turn the *child-element* into a *sibling-element*.

Comment: This is the only solution that will work, particularly the second variant. Some filters can't be reversed, such as `blur`. My problem was worse, as I had an image as background of the parent `div` and I wanted to only blur that. Solution: turn the background into its own div (sibling to the children). Now I can blur that one and leave the others alone. I still can't understand answers like "incorporate the other answers" or, more generically, answers from people that did not even try before posting. Thank you @Rourin

Comment: I'm really happy this approach worked for you too, @Ricardo.