# Why is hue-rotate(180deg) not its own inverse?

Tags: html, css, svg, colors, css-filters

[The `hue-rotate()` filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/hue-rotate()) "rotates the hue of an element ... specified as an angle". If this were true, `filter: hue-rotate(180deg) hue-rotate(180deg)` would have no effect. But it definitely *does* have an effect:

```css
.square {
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 154, 0, 1) 10%, rgba(208, 222, 33, 1) 20%, rgba(79, 220, 74, 1) 30%, rgba(63, 218, 216, 1) 40%, rgba(47, 201, 226, 1) 50%, rgba(28, 127, 238, 1) 60%, rgba(95, 21, 242, 1) 70%, rgba(186, 12, 248, 1) 80%, rgba(251, 7, 217, 1) 90%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.double-invert {
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="square">filter: none</div>
<div class="square double-invert">filter: hue-rotate(180deg) hue-rotate(180deg)</div>
```

What is happening here? What does `hue-rotate` actually do? And how can I achieve a hue rotation that *is* its own inverse? (Or, how can I come up with a filter that inverts the hue rotation?)

**Update:** following Temani Aiff's answer, it seems that `hue-rotate(180deg)` is actually a matrix multiplication. However, it's unclear what matrix it's actually using. The following shows that we can reimplement the SVG filter `type="hueRotate"` as a raw matrix, but the CSS filter `hue-rotate` does not actually match either of those:

```css
.square {
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 154, 0, 1) 10%, rgba(208, 222, 33, 1) 20%, rgba(79, 220, 74, 1) 30%, rgba(63, 218, 216, 1) 40%, rgba(47, 201, 226, 1) 50%, rgba(28, 127, 238, 1) 60%, rgba(95, 21, 242, 1) 70%, rgba(186, 12, 248, 1) 80%, rgba(251, 7, 217, 1) 90%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.hue-rotate {
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
}

.hue-rotate-svg {
  filter: url(#svgHueRotate180);
}

.hue-rotate-svg-matrix {
  filter: url(#svgHueRotate180Matrix);
}
```

```html
<svg style="position: absolute; top: -99999px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="svgHueRotate180">
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="hueRotate"
        values="180" />
  </filter>
  
  <!-- Following matrix calculated following spec -->
  <filter id="svgHueRotate180Matrix">
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
        values="
-0.574 1.43  0.144 0 0
 0.426 0.43  0.144 0 0
 0.426 1.43 -0.856 0 0
 0     0     0     1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>

<div class="square">filter: none</div>
<div class="square hue-rotate">filter: hue-rotate(180deg)</div>
<div class="square hue-rotate-svg">using SVG hueRotate</div>
<div class="square hue-rotate-svg-matrix">using SVG raw matrix</div>
```

At least in Chrome and Firefox, `hue-rotate` is doing something distinct from the SVG filters. But what is it doing?!

Comment: Why shouldn't it have an effect?

Comment: @cloned because in ordinary geometry, those rotations add to a single rotation by 360deg, which is equivalent to 0deg

Comment: Alternatively: because if `hue-rotate(Xdeg)` means taking `hsl(h,s,l)` to `hsl(h+X, s, l)`, then `hue-rotate(180deg) hue-rotate(180deg)` takes `hsl(h,s,l)` to `hsl(h+360deg, s, l)`, which is equivalent to `hsl(h,s,l)`

Comment: This might happen due to conversion between `rgba` and `hsla` as some colors cannot be converted correctly. And since `filter` values are being applied one-by-one (the next one is being applied to the *result* of the previous one) the conversion bias is getting even worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hue-rotate(X) hue-rotate(X)` is not equivalent to `hue-rotate(X+X)` as shown below:

```css
.square {
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 154, 0, 1) 10%, rgba(208, 222, 33, 1) 20%, rgba(79, 220, 74, 1) 30%, rgba(63, 218, 216, 1) 40%, rgba(47, 201, 226, 1) 50%, rgba(28, 127, 238, 1) 60%, rgba(95, 21, 242, 1) 70%, rgba(186, 12, 248, 1) 80%, rgba(251, 7, 217, 1) 90%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.single-invert {
  filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
}

.double-invert {
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="square">filter: none</div>
<div class="square single-invert">filter: hue-rotate(360deg) </div>
<div class="square double-invert">filter: hue-rotate(180deg) hue-rotate(180deg)</div>
```

To understand you need to dig in to the math formula. From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#huerotateEquivalent) the `hue-rotate()` is:

```
<filter id="hue-rotate">
  <feColorMatrix type="hueRotate" values="[angle]"/>
</filter>
```

and for `feColorMatrix` we have have a [matrix calculation](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#feColorMatrixElement). I will give you the matrix for each case after the math (you can try it yourself  following the specification)

for `180deg`

```
-0.574  1.43   0.144
 0.426  0.43   0.144
 0.426  1.43  -0.856
```

For `360deg` it's the identity matrix

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

When you apply two filters, it means you will use the same matrix twice which is nothing but a matrix multiplication. So you have to do the below multiplication:

```
|-0.574  1.43   0.144|    |-0.574  1.43   0.144|
| 0.426  0.43   0.144| x  | 0.426  0.43   0.144|
| 0.426  1.43  -0.856|    | 0.426  1.43  -0.856|
```

to get:

```
1     8.326  -1.387
1.387 1       0
0     0       1
```

And it's not the identity so filtering twice using `hue-rotate(180deg)` is not equivalent to `hue-rotate(360deg)`. In other words, don't see it as "sum" but rather as a "multiplication".

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks! So the MDN docs are misleading - it's not really a "hue rotation" at all, but a linear approximation to something like that which also preserves lightness ...

Comment: Now my remaining confusion is - the matrix you gave (and which I also get from following the spec) does not actually seem to give the same result ... I'll update my question to show what I mean

Comment: I've added my confusion to the end of the question - it seems like your answer is right by the spec, and yet Chrome and Firefox are doing something rather different ...

Comment: @jameshfisher the MDN is correct, the Spec also say the same here: https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#funcdef-filter-hue-rotate but it seems I need to recheck the Spec again because I assumed that the SVG filter will give the same result as the CSS filter that's why I used the calculation of the SVG one but maybe there is a difference with the CSS implementation

Comment: @jameshfisher: HSL is also an approximation: same L doesn't mean same lightness. Check your first band in both snippet. Does they seem constant lightness? Blue and yellow? In short: it is a trade-off of fast and parallelizable in CPU (and low memory) vs. exact, complex (you need to be much more precise on definitions, you may get surprises on some screens, etc., and you need to perform float arithmetic with complex functions). Also "hue" has a strange degree meaning in normally used HSL.